# If $G$ is any infinite cyclic group then how do you prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=\{e_G, -e_G\}$

Tags: group-theory

What I've done so far:

Say $G$ is generated by some fixed $a$ and $f \in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Then suppose $f(a) = \alpha \in G$. How do I go from here to show that $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\alpha=a^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$. As $f$ has an inverse and $\alpha$ must be a generator of $G$, we also conclude that $a=\alpha^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$. Hence $a^{nm}=a$. This is only possible if $nm=1$ as otherwise we'd have a *finite* cyclic group. The only solutions to $nm=1$ with $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ are $n=m=\pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

then observe $f(a^n)=\alpha^n$ hence range is generated by $\alpha$ hence range will be same as $G$ if $\alpha$ is a generator which is possible only if $\alpha=a$ or $\alpha={a}^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Infinite cyclic groups are isometric to a group  Integers okay.  So it is enough to show this result holds on integers. Automorphism maps generators to generators so let's us take 1 is generator of integer then we have only two choice either 1 goes to 1 or - 1. (otherwise image group is proper subset of codomain).